# How to add multiple section in admin form magento2

Tags: magento2, adminform

**I have created custom form in magento2 admin panel.**

> Now I want to add one more section same as Tab, let say 'Tab1'.

[image]

**This is my general.php file.**

> Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Custom/Edit/Tab/General.php

```
<?php
namespace Bls\Stdprofile\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit\Tab;
class Tab extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
      /* @var $model \Magento\Cms\Model\Page */
      $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('stdprofile_custom');
      $isElementDisabled = false;
      /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
      $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

      $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend' => __('Tab')));

      if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array('name' => 'id'));
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'col1',
        'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'col1',
            'label' => __('Company Name:'),
            'title' => __('Company Name:'),
            /*'required' => true,*/
        )
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'col2',
        'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'col2',
            'label' => __('Address:'),
            'title' => __('Address:'),
            /*'required' => true,*/
        )
    );

    if (!$model->getId()) {
        $model->setData('status', $isElementDisabled ? '2' : '1');
    }

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();   
}

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a multiple tabs in admin form by below code

> Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Custom/Edit/Tab/General.php

```
 <?php
    namespace Bls\Stdprofile\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit\Tab;
    class Tab extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
         */
        protected $_systemStore;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
            array $data = array()
        ) {
            $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
            parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare form
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
          /* @var $model \Magento\Cms\Model\Page */
          $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('stdprofile_custom');
          $isElementDisabled = false;
          /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
          $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

          $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');

          $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend' => __('Tab')));

          if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array('name' => 'id'));
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'col1',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'col1',
                'label' => __('Company Name:'),
                'title' => __('Company Name:'),
                /*'required' => true,*/
            )
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'col2',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'col2',
                'label' => __('Address:'),
                'title' => __('Address:'),
                /*'required' => true,*/
            )
        );
      //multiple tabs in admin form
      $second_fieldset = $form->addFieldset('second_fieldset', array('legend' => __('Tab1')));

        $second_fieldset ->addField(
            'tab1_col1',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'tab1_col1',
                'label' => __('Required Name:'),
                'title' => __('Required Name:'),
            )
        );

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('status', $isElementDisabled ? '2' : '1');
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();   
    }

        /**
         * Prepare label for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return __('Tab');
        }

        /**
         * Prepare title for tab
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return __('Tab');
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Check permission for passed action
         *
         * @param string $resourceId
         * @return bool
         */
        protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
        {
            return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
        }
    }
```